# Ubuntu Server 16.10 & iOS devices recharge

Tags: usb, battery, iphone, ipad, charging

When connecting an iPad Pro or an iPhone 7+ to an USB port (of an X99 mobo) the devices show "Not charging" next to the battery icon.

I tried googling this question around and the only solution (the most recent) I found, ipad-charge, it doesn't seem to work under Ubuntu Server 16.10.

I'm at a dead-end, any help?

Thank you.

P.S.
This is an headless server I wish I could just plug a device to for a sporadic charge, without needing to ssh the server to mount or acivate something, just plug and charge. Is it posssible with these apple devices?

Answer (score 2):

I've been experiencing similar issues with Ubuntu 17.10 where my device appears to be charging but isn't really.

Unfortunately I haven't found a way to fix this without command-line access to the machine - the only way I've found to fix this is by restarting the `usbmuxd` daemon, e.g.,

`% sudo systemctl restart usbmuxd`

and then reconnecting my phone.

Comment: didn't help for me (ubuntu 18.04), after this command ubuntu don't detect device (not present in list of devices by lsusb)